# SQL. full range of dates for every user

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see code below. For every `Underwriter` that exists that is in a given month, I need every single date in the month and the given `Underwriter`. Thank you so much

**Original Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Table6] ([Underwriter] nvarchar(10), [UW_First] date, [UW_Last] date)

INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Kim', '11/1/2019', '11/30/2019')
INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Kim', '12/1/2019', '12/31/2019')
INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Sarah', '11/1/2019', '11/30/2019')
INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Sarah', '12/1/2019', '12/31/2019')
INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Rebecca', '11/1/2019', '11/30/2019')
```

```
Underwriter | UW_First   | UW_Last     |
------------------------------------------
Kim         | 11/1/2019  | 11/30/2019  |
Kim         | 12/1/2019  | 12/31/2019  |
Sarah       | 11/1/2019  | 11/30/2019  |
Sarah       | 12/1/2019  | 12/31/2019  |
Rebecca     | 11/1/2019  | 11/30/2019  |
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Underwriter    | Date       |
------------------------------
Kim            | 11/1/2019  |
Kim            | 11/2/2019  |
Kim             ...
Kim            | 11/30/2019 |
Kim            | 12/1/2019  |
Kim             ...
Kim            | 12/30/2019 |
Sarah          | 11/1/2019  |
Sarah          | 11/2/2019  |
Sarah           ...
Sarah          | 11/30/2019 |
Sarah          | 12/1/2019  |
Sarah           ...
Sarah          | 12/30/2019 |
Rebecca        | 11/1/2019  |
Rebecca        | 11/2/2019  |
Rebecca         ...
Rebecca        | 11/30/2019 |
```

*Please note that Rebecca should not have dates for 12/1/2019 to 12/31/2019*

**Attempted Code**

```
SELECT [Underwriter], ________ AS [Date]
FROM [Table6]
CROSS JOIN [] = [UW_First] Between [UW_Last]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what didn't work?

Comment: You need a table of dates - trivial searching will find many examples of generating that information whether you do that dynamically or statically (preferred). Once you do that, you then need to collapse your underwriter data into a set - a min and max date per underwriter (and perhaps per month - that isn't clear). Break your goal into digestible pieces and clarify it.

Comment: And why are you using datetime rather than date? Don't encourage problems by using the wrong datatype!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Tally, they are really fast at such operations:

```
/*
Underwriter | UW_First   | UW_Last     |
------------------------------------------
Kim         | 11/1/2019  | 11/30/2019  |
Kim         | 12/1/2019  | 12/31/2019  |
Sarah       | 11/1/2019  | 11/30/2019  |
Sarah       | 12/1/2019  | 12/31/2019  |
Rebecca     | 11/1/2019  | 11/30/2019  |
*/
--Create sample table

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Underwriter varchar(10),
                            UW_First date,
                            UW_Last date);
GO

--Insert sample data    
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Underwriter,UW_First,UW_Last)
SELECT RTRIM(U),
       CONVERT(date,F,101),
       CONVERT(date,L,101)
FROM (VALUES('Kim    ','11/1/2019','11/30/2019'),
            ('Kim    ','12/1/2019','12/31/2019'),
            ('Sarah  ','11/1/2019','11/30/2019'),
            ('Sarah  ','12/1/2019','12/31/2019'),
            ('Rebecca','11/1/2019','11/30/2019'))V(U, F, L);
GO

--Start creating the Tally    
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
--Create the tally, using Cross Joins.
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY,UW_First,UW_Last))+1 FROM dbo.YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1000 days
--And then make the data set
SELECT YT.Underwriter,
       DATEADD(DAY,T.I,YT.UW_First) AS [Date]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON T.I <= DATEDIFF(DAY,YT.UW_First,YT.UW_Last)
ORDER BY YT.Underwriter,
         [Date];
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain why you chose 10 NULLs and what if I need this table to expand to 100000 rows, would I go to N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6?

Comment: 10 is easy to work in multiples of @TiffanyC . `10`, `100`, `1000`, `10000`, etc, etc. And yes, just cross join to `N` more. You have `10*10^(N-1)` rows (where `N` is the number of cross joins to `N`).

Comment: Also, @TiffanyC , 100,000 days would be almost 300 years; I did *assume* you wouldn't need that many. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need recursive *cte* :

```
with cte as (
    select Underwriter, UW_First, UW_Last
    from Table6 t
    union all
    select Underwriter, dateadd(day, 1, c.UW_First), UW_Last
    from cte c
    where dateadd(day, 1, UW_First) <= UW_Last
)

select c.Underwriter, c.UW_First as Date
from cte c
order by Underwriter, UW_First;
```

Comment: But [rCTEs are so slow](http://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/)...